# Dynamically adjust fixture value in ruby tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing

I'm testing my Rails application and a specific part of the project looks at how long ago a user was created. If I write a fixture for this, the only way I can think of right now is to define multiple users with different `created_at` values.

Is there a way to dynamically define the `created_at` value per test? I'd like to just define one user and each test will pass in a different value for `created_at`. If this is not possible, is there a better way I can test this?

Comment: you can look into [timecop](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop) gem

Comment: Change fixtures to factories and create users with needed attributes easily. Like `let(:old_user) { create :user, created_at: Time.now - 3.years }`